# XCode Ruby script output only visible on error

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have ruby script build phases to bump the version number and record the build date.
They work fine, but I want to echo the new values to the build log in the log navigator.
If there is an error in the script, the  puts  and  print  commands do echo their values, but I want to see them when the code works.

Here's the script:

```
# add build date to Info.plist
the_date=`date`
print "date: "+the_date
puts "fooooooooooooo"

x2="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Set :BuildDateString " + the_date+"\" " + ENV['TARGET_BUILD_DIR'] +"/"+ ENV['INFOPLIST_PATH']
exec(x2)
```

I don't see the "date: ", nor the "fooooo" in the output UNLESS there is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output to [stderr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_error_.28stderr.29). In Ruby, you can do that with `warn`. For example:

```
the_date=`date`
warn "date: "+the_date
warn "fooooooooooooo"
…
```

generates the following output in the build log:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  It solves the problem, but I'm still unclear why this worked in previous versions of the SDK.

Comment: @Rayfleck This could be either a regression bug or an actual change. Since there’s no reliable changelog provided by Apple, you could file a radar if you think this behaviour should be reverted.